# windowSoftInputMode adjustResize

Tags: java, android, xml, resize, android-manifest

Thanks for your help!

I am trying to have my bottom LinearLayout (which holds a button) show on screen at all times 10dp above bottom. There is an EditText above this Linearlayout which I would like to resize according to how much text has been entered.

In my manifest I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` which resizes my EditText, but always pushes the LinearLayout I want to show off screen. (When enough text is entered)

**PLEASE HELP ME PLACE A LINEARLAYOUT 10DP ABOVE KEYBOARD WHEN ENOUGH TEXT HAS BEEN ENTERED WHILE ONLY RESIZING MY EDITTEXT. THANK YOU.**

(I am going for something similar to this version of twitter below)

I am using ActionBarSherlock to get a specific theme. (Not sure if that matters)

[Similar to this version of Twitter for android (image)](http://img2.mobile-patterns.com/img/full/1363118132913-2013-03-03%2018.43.33.png)

activity_main.xml

```
<!-- MAIN LAYOUT -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainactivity_main_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp">


<!-- TOP BAR -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainactivity_top_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- TITLE -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mainactivity_edittext_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.02"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:textColor="#262626"
        android:hint="@string/title_hint"
        android:maxLength="20" />

    <!-- COLOR CHANGER BUTTON -->
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/mainactivity_button_color_changer"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/color_changer_custom"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickAction" />

    <!-- OVERFLOW MENU BUTTON -->
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/mainactivity_button_overflow"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/overflow_custom"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickAction" />

</LinearLayout>

    <!-- BODY -->
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/mainactivity_edittext_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/backer1"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="20" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#262626"
        android:hint="@string/body_hint" />

     <!-- BOTTOM BAR -->
     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/mainactivity_bottom_layout"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:background="@drawable/bottomless"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <!-- BUTTON -->
         <Button 
            android:id="@+id/mainactivity_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/close_custom"
            android:text="@string/close_text"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text_color" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mikemilla.www"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mikemilla.pinitnotes.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/mytransparent.windowNoTitle"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```